# Changing CSS from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

DOM changes from angularjs controllers are not a good practice. In my application, after clicking on a link, I am changing class of an html element inside ngView. the intended behaviour is, that i have three divs, and I am changing if the middle one is shown or not. I am doing this from a controller. I have read, that doing DOM manipulation should be done in a directive, but my mind is not broad enough to find a solution. Please, if you have a suggestion, I will be glad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ng-class](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngClass).

e.g:

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/eTTZj/75/

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("click", function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function() {
            scope.boolChangeClass = !scope.boolChangeClass;
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

Some HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div>One</div>
    <div ng-class="{'my-class':boolChangeClass}">Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <button click>Click me</button>
</div>
```

When you click the button, the class of the center div will change depending on the boolen value set within your scope.

Comment: Thank you! So not a lot of refactoring is needed :)

Comment: @MartinPalis this answer is partially correct. You should be using ng-class.. But instead of a custom click directive you should be using ng-click...

Comment: In the end, I am not so sure. Why to use ng-click instead of custom click directive? Assuming that I want to pack my directive and let it be used as-is, without any need to put callback functions somewhere to my code, isn't the cusom click directive a better solution?